# Factor ring induced by the ideal generated by x(x-1)(x-2)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the ring $R:=\mathbb C[x]/I$, where $I$ is the ideal in $\mathbb C[x]$ generated by $x(x-1)(x-2)$.

> Show that the evaluation map $\mathbb C[x]\to \mathbb C,\ p(x)\mapsto p(\alpha)$, for $\alpha\in\{0,1,2\}$ induces a well-defined ring homorphism $R\to \mathbb C$.

I have issues with the "well-defined" part.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induced map takes $f+I$ to $f(\alpha)$, so for well-definedness, you only need to check that $I$ is contained in the kernel of the evaluation map on $C[x]$. That way, if $f=g+r$ for some $r\in I$, so that $f+I=g+I$ in $C[x]/I$, then $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$, and the induced map is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

*Well-defined* means that if $r=s$ in $R$, then $\bar\varepsilon(r)=\bar\varepsilon(s)$, where $\bar\varepsilon$ is the map induced by $\varepsilon(p)=p(\alpha)$.

The issue of well-definedness arises because $\bar\varepsilon$ is defined based on a *representative* of $r$ as in $\bar\varepsilon(\bar p)=p(\alpha)$. In principle, it might happen that $\bar p = \bar q$ but $p(\alpha)\neq q(\alpha)$.